# Angular + Typescript code convention

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am using a combination of Angularjs + Typescript for my project. I am searching for a good code convention. There are some some good examples for the two technologies separately. For example I follow this one when using TypeScript:

https://github.com/Platypi/style_typescript#introduction

But couldn't find a good one for the combination of Angularjs + Typescript. To be a little bit more specific, for example, I need a convention on how to write directives with the typescript syntax etc.

I could not find any good articles on the topic. If someone can share something on the topic it will be great. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure how to do it using Angular 1.x. Angular2 supports typescript by default. My github tutorial: https://github.com/agongdai/Joy/tree/joy-angular2

Answer (score 1):

I have followed [this](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/master/examples/typescript-angular) projects structure when writing angularjs + typescript.

Since directives are actually factory functions writing directives will be done in the same way:

```
module Directives{
  export function MyDirective(optionalService): ng.IDirective{
     var myDirective = {};
     myDirective.restrict = 'A';
     myDirective.link = function(scope, elem){};
     //etc
     return myDirective;
  }
  MyDirective.$inject = ["optionalService"];
}

app.directive("myDirective", Directives.MyDirective);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Angular1.5+ you can follow Angular2 Component style:

```
class DemoController implements ng.IComponentController {
    public static $inject = [
        'Service1',
    ];
    constructor(private Service1: IService1) {
        //
    }

    public $onInit(): void {
        // ---
    }

    public $postLink(): void {
        // ---
    }

    // ---
}

export const DemoComponent = {
    selector: 'demoComponent',
    bindings: {
        prop1: '<',
        prop2: '<',
    },
    controller: DemoController,
    templateUrl: require('./your-tpl.html'),
};
```

And somewhere in your module, you can register this component:

```
.component(DemoComponent.selector, DemoComponent)
```

For creating directives this code style is also pretty nice:

```
export class MyDemoDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    public restrict: string;

    public static $inject: string[] = [
        'Service1',
        'Service2',
    ];

    constructor(private Service1: IService1, private Service2: IService2) {
        this.restrict = 'A';
        // ---
    }

    public link(...) {
        // ---
    }

    public static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
        const directive = (Service1: IService1, Service2: IService2) => {
            return new MyDemoDirective($filter, User);
        };
        return directive;
    }
}
```